# To say "Like Google is swallowing it whole": "verschlucken" or "schlucken"?

Tags: word-choice

> Als würde Google alles **verschlucken**.
>
> or: Als würde Google alles **schlucken**.

I wonder which verb is better suited to conveying this figurative meaning and if there are some nuances involved?

**EDIT** from OP's comment:

The context is in the sense that: Google is now taking over everything that has so far been controlled by other companies.

Comment: Both are okay, but *alles schlucken* also means *to believe in a big lie told by someone* and *to swallow your own tears*. A better alternative for your sentences is **verschlingen**.

Comment: Was willst Du ausdrücken?

Comment: Presumably both are OKish but imprecise. More context needed for nuances..

Comment: @LangLangC Hi. In the sense that: Google is now taking over everything that has so far been controlled by other companies.

Comment: @Janka gave a perfect answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use »sich einverleiben«.

> - Als würde sich Google alles einverleiben, was eine Firma ist.
> - Als würde sich Google alles einverleiben, was ein Geschäftsmodell ist.

However, use of »schlucken« or »verschlucken« instead (no difference in meaning) would also be okay.

Comment: Von der Gestaltung her ist offensichtlich am wichtigsten, was Du benutzen würde. Das war aber nicht die Frage. Hättest Du eine Begründung dafür geliefert, dann könnte man darüber nachdenken, ob diese vielleicht für mehr als nur Dich relevant sein könnte. Eine solche findet sich aber nicht. Insofern ist das mehr ein Kommentar und eine Meinung, als eine Antwort.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Frage beantworte ich, indem ich sage: _No difference in meaning_.

Comment: Ohne empirischer Sprachforscher zu sein vermute ich, dass die Sprachvorlieben und Gewohnheiten stark von folgen Faktoren abhängen: Bildungsstand, soziale Klasse, Alter, Region, Geschlecht. Diese Merkmale sind hier sicher nicht repräsentativ vertreten, sondern mehr Gebildete (Abiturabschluss +), Alter 19-60, vornehmlich Männer, Region gemischt. Daher kann es sein, dass Deine Vorlieben von vielen geteilt werden, ohne dass sie repräsentativ sind. So fügen sie der Antwort Rauschen zu, sind aber das erste und am auffälligsten formatiert. Das finde ich einen schlechten Antwortstil.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn du Antworten runterzählst, die dir stilistisch missfallen, denken andere, sie wäre inhaltlich falsch.

Comment: Das wäre aber dumm. Sie sollten nur denken, dass eine Person der Meinung war, sie sei nicht nützlich. Wenn Leute überzogene Schlüsse ziehen ist das deren Problem.